# What is the correct way to reference the indexes in a permutations cycle notation?

Tags: notation, permutations

I have a permutation in cycle notation, say this one
$$\underbrace{(123)}_{=:C_1}\underbrace{(45)}_{=:C_2}\underbrace{(6)}_{=:C_3}$$
with cycle $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$. Later on I have to use these indexes which are included in specific cycles, i.e. I would like to reference to every $C_k$ as an index set, so that I can write $\forall i\in C_1$ for example. I cannot remember anybody taking elements from a cycle. Is it correct to write it like this? Or is it wrong, since $C_1$ is neither a set $\{1,2,3\}$, nor a tupel $(1,2,3)$, for which that notation would be correct? What is the correct notation?

**Edit for further clarification:**

It is important to be able to iterate over the elements of $C_1$ in an order which corresponds to the cycle. So I would like to be able to write a sum like
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 C_1(i)\;x_i = 1x_1+2x_2+3x_3$$
which is equivalent to $3x_1+1x_2+2x_3$ and $2x_1+3x_2+1x_3$, but not to $3x_1+2x_2+1x_3$ etc., since the cycle $(123)$ is equivalent to $(312)$ and $(231)$.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the cycle $(123)$ is actually a permutation on $\{1, 2, \ldots, 6\}$ (the points $4$, $5$ and $6$ are fixed). You could call the set $\{1,2,3\}$ the *support* of the cycle $(123)$. More generally, you could define, for each permutation $\sigma$, the *support of $\sigma$* as the set $S(\sigma) = \{x \mid \sigma(x) \not= x\}$.

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought about the support, but often I have to iterate over the indexes of a cycle like in a sum $\sum_{i=1}^3...C_1(i)...$. Then I need $C_1(i)$ to have an order corresponding to the cycle (i.e. $C_1(1)=1$, $C_1(2)=2$, $C_1(3)=3$ or $3, 1, 2$ or $2, 3, 1$) , so I cannot use a set.